# Why isn't my PHP form working?

Tags: php, html

It always redirects to the success page, but I never receive the email. I've tried rewriting both the PHP and the HTML, but it won't fix anything and I can never find google pages about how to fix this situation (everything appears to be fine, and most people have problems with receiving an email and not a redirect page). I'm not very familiar with PHP but can't find any errors. This is a contact page for a business website.

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$to = "arsilhavy@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact From $name";
$mailheader = "From: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Message $message \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $mailheader, $formcontent);
     if (mail($to, $subject, $body))
    header('Location: success.html');
 else
    print "Something went wrong" ;
?>
```

HTML:

```html
  <div id="copy">
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" name="contact">
 <div class="name">Name</div>
 <input required type="text" name="name" style="border: solid 1px #081B26; width: 200px;" value="">
 <div class="email">Email</div>
 <input required type="email" name="email" style="border: solid 1px #081B26; width: 200px;" value="">
 <div class="tel">Phone</div>
 <input type="tel" name="phone" style="border: solid 1px #081B26; width: 200px;" value="">
 <div class="message">Message</div>
 <textarea required name="message" rows="6" cols="25" style="border: solid 1px #081B26; width: 200px;" value=""></textarea>
    <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Send" class="send">
 <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="clear">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a library already to send emails. Take a look at swift mailer.

Comment: You're calling `mail()` twice, and each time one of the parameters is undefined. You need to use a debugger and preferably a good IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send Mails from PHP you will never be happy with this way. I strongly recommend to you to use something like PHPMailer (Download and Instructions here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer ) If you have an existing and properly working E-Mail use this one and configure PHP Mailer to log in with this adress and send Mails via SMTP. If you need an example I can provide one to you, but it is pretty strqaight foreward and very well explained on the given link.

You did not receive any E-Mail because (most likely) your E-Mail did NOT pass the spam filters on your destination e-mail adress. There are quite a lot of meta information and in general also certificates required for your mail to pass the spamfilters of most to all e-mail provider.

Comment: Didn't know things like this existed, my teacher in school told me that this is the only way do code PHP. (:

Comment: You must have had a horrible teacher. But sending emails with PHP is really not that easy, I spend many hours figuering it out...

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to run this from your development computer? Chances are your PHP installation isn't configured to send mails.

1. Open your `php.ini` file.
2. Search for `[mail function]`
3. Edit settings to your needs